# Javascript return enclosing function

Tags: javascript, refactoring, return, dry, decoupling

I have a simple scenario in which I check if something exists before adding it, if it does, I `return` the function (hence exiting). I use this pattern many times and I would like to decouple it in another simple function.

```
function onEvent(e){
     if( this.has(e) )
          return
     this.add(e);
     // More logic different on an event-basis
}
```

I would like to decouple it like so:

```
function safeAdd(e){
     if( this.has(e) )
           return
     this.add(e);
}

function onEvent(e){
     safeAdd(e);
     // More logic
}
```

But obviously doing so just `return`s `safeAdd` and doesn't exit from `onEvent`, and the rest of the logic gets executed anyways.

I know I could do something like:

```
function safeAdd(e){
     if( this.has(e) )
           return false
     this.add(e);
     return true
}

function onEvent(e){
     if( !safeAdd(e) )
         return
     // More logic
}
```

But, since I repeat this a lot, I would like to be as concise as possible.

Comment: That's as concise as it gets (besides for some fiddling within the `safeAdd` function).

Comment: It's possible to pass in the "more logic" via a function "pointer" (not sure javascript calls it this) and then have safeAdd() call that additional function when the entry is added to the list.  However, I doubt that qualifies as more concise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could turn it inside out with something like this:

```
function safeAdd(callback) {
    return function(e) {
        if(this.has(e))
            return false;
        this.add(e);
        return callback.call(this, e);
    };
}
```

and then you could do things like this:

```
var obj = {
    onEvent: safeAdd(function(e) {
        console.log('more logic', e);
    }),
    onPancakes: safeAdd(function(e) {
        console.log('pancakes', e);
    }),
    has: function(e) { /* ... */ },
    add: function(e) { /* ... */ }
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/T6pBQ/

And if you need to support more arguments in your functions, switch [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and use [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) instead of `e`:

```
function safeAdd(callback) {
    return function() {
        if(this.has(arguments[0]))
            return false;
        this.add(arguments[0]);
        return callback.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/3muzg/

Comment: Accepted and upvoted (mostly for the `onPancakes` method)! Amazing answer. I have two questions, though, since I am not so fluent with the `call()` and `apply()`. #1: Why do you need the `return function()` in `safeAdd()`? #2: Isn't `arguments[0]` referring to `callback`?

Comment: We return an (anonymous) function so that we can add our wrapper while making it look like the `callback` is all that gets called. `arguments` represents the arguments to the closest surrounding function, that would be the anonymous `return function() { ... }` function in this case, not the `safeAdd`. `call` and `apply` are methods on functions that allow you to (a) call a function with whatever `this` you need and (b) `apply` allows you to pass arguments without having to know what the arguments actually are, you just send in an array instead of individual arguments.

Comment: Mm, not sure I understand entirely: I understand the reason for the wrapper in the `apply` case, so that `arguments` refers to the returned function. But in the case of `call` in which we already pass `e`, what would happen if we remove the `return function()` statement?

Comment: But `e` isn't known when we call `safeAdd`, `e` is known later when `onEvent` or `onPancakes` gets called. We run `safeAdd` will building `obj`, the functions that `safeAdd` returns get called later.

Comment: Cool. Functions building functions can be a bit strange the first time you come across it but it is a super useful technique once you get the hang of it.

Comment: Any suggested resources for learning that? Not necessarely "tutorials" or articles (even if I like the theory), but if this is a common pattern in some big opensource project for example (like jQuery or whatnot).

Comment: Looking for things on "functional programming in JavaScript" might help. I've been doing these sorts of things so long that I don't know any resources for it, sorry.